# Android DevicePolicyManager setMaximumTimeToLock not working

Tags: android

I have an app that sets the MaxTimeToLock by the DevicePolicyManager.setMaximumTimeLock.

This doesnt seem to work. It only turns of the screen but doesnt prompt for password once the screen is turned on.

Device being used: Samsung Nexus S running 2.3.4